# How deleted, replaced file at share folder

Tags: c#

Hello I have a problem with deleting and replacing files at share folder
I have full access.

"access to the path was denied"

The copy function works well in both directions.
(but I have to delete files manually).

- SERVER - >>> PC
- SERVER <<< - PC

  The program connects to the file server under another user and manipulate with files (copy files worked fine, delete files doesn't work replace doesn't work).

  ```
  private void replaceFile(string source, string sourceName ,string destination)
      {
          try
          {
              using (new Impersonator(username(), domain(), password()))
              {
                  //File.delete(destination);
                  //File.Copy(source, destination, true);

                  File.Replace(source, destination, null);
              }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
          }
      }
  ```

  ---

  ```
  private void copyFile(string source, string destination)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (new Impersonator(username(), domain(), password()))
                    {
                        File.Copy(source, destination, true);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
            }
  ```

  ---

  ```
  using System;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  using System.Security.Principal;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace IFS_FileManager
  {

      public enum LogonType
      {
          LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2,
          LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3,
          LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4,
          LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5,
          LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7,
          LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8, // Win2K or higher
          LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9 // Win2K or higher
      };

      public enum LogonProvider
      {
          LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0,
          LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1,
          LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2,
          LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3
      };

      public enum ImpersonationLevel
      {
          SecurityAnonymous = 0,
          SecurityIdentification = 1,
          SecurityImpersonation = 2,
          SecurityDelegation = 3
      }

      class Win32NativeMethods
      {
          [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
          public static extern int LogonUser(string lpszUserName,
               string lpszDomain,
               string lpszPassword,
               int dwLogonType,
               int dwLogonProvider,
               ref IntPtr phToken);

          [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
          public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
                int impersonationLevel,
                ref IntPtr hNewToken);



          [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
          public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

          [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
          public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
      }


      public class Impersonator : IDisposable
      {
          private WindowsImpersonationContext _wic;

          public Impersonator(string userName, string domainName, string password, LogonType logonType, LogonProvider logonProvider)
          {
              Impersonate(userName, domainName, password, logonType, logonProvider);
          }

          public Impersonator(string userName, string domainName, string password)
          {
              Impersonate(userName, domainName, password, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT);
          }

          public Impersonator() { }


          public void Dispose()
          {
              UndoImpersonation();
          }

          public void Impersonate(string userName, string domainName, string password)
          {
              Impersonate(userName, domainName, password, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT);
          }

          public void Impersonate(string userName, string domainName, string password, LogonType logonType, LogonProvider logonProvider)
          {
              UndoImpersonation();

              IntPtr logonToken = IntPtr.Zero;
              IntPtr logonTokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
              try
              {
                  // revert to the application pool identity, saving the identity of the current requestor
                  _wic = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero);

                  // do logon & impersonate
                  if (Win32NativeMethods.LogonUser(userName,domainName,password,(int)logonType,(int)logonProvider,ref logonToken) != 0)
                  {
                      if (Win32NativeMethods.DuplicateToken(logonToken, (int)ImpersonationLevel.SecurityImpersonation, ref logonTokenDuplicate) != 0)
                      {
                          var wi = new WindowsIdentity(logonTokenDuplicate);
                          wi.Impersonate(); 
                          // discard the returned identity context (which is the context of the application pool)
                      }
                      else
                          MessageBox.Show("\n " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                  }
                  else
                      MessageBox.Show("\n " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
              }
              finally
              {
                  if (logonToken != IntPtr.Zero)
                      Win32NativeMethods.CloseHandle(logonToken);

                  if (logonTokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                      Win32NativeMethods.CloseHandle(logonTokenDuplicate);
              }
          }

          /// <summary>
          /// Stops impersonation.
          /// </summary>
          private void UndoImpersonation()
          {
              // restore saved requestor identity
              if (_wic != null)
                  _wic.Undo();
              _wic = null;
          }

      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Define *doesn't work*, what exception is thrown?

Comment: Do you have the full error message when trying to delete?

Comment: e.Message:
{"Přístup k cestě \\\\fs\\DOC\\DOC-1167358-1-A1-1.BMP byl odepřen."}'
Translate:
Access to path \\\\ fs \\ DOC \\ DOC-1167358-1-A1-1.BMP was denied
System.Exception {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}

e.Data:
{System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}